# Bought a Vx2460h monitor that doesn't get audio output from iPad 3 or MacBook Pro bought late 2011

Tags: audio, external-display, osx-mountain-lion, ipad-3

Any idea what this may be? I really don't think it's a hardware thing but I can still return it, I'd like to exhaust any other possibilities first though.

It did come with a cd but I cannot use any of the apps because they're Power PC and I'm running Mountain Lion. =/

Comment: How are you connecting the iPad and the Mac to the monitor?

Comment: I am using a thunderbolt to hdmi cable for the mac (that I have tested before and I know carries sound) and I'm using an adapter for iPad like this one: http://compare.ebay.com/like/160876064177?var=lv&ltyp=AllFixedPriceItemTypes&var=sbar which I've also tried before and works =/